# How to change android studio Operation language

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a Chinese, and I can't get used to the android studio's default language. I know the key to this question is the *resources_en.jar file.*

I have unzipped the package. But I don't know what to do next. How to change the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the language, follow these steps:

1. upzip the file resources_en.jar in Android Studio\lib
2. get the dict messages which has .properties file.
3. use JAVA IDE to open this file, and  then change the text to the desired language.
4. use java tool to zip these dict to create the file resources_en.jar
5. backup the old resources_en.jar an replace it with the custom resources_en.jar