# Android Studio: Default language

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android studio default language has been changed automatically. Does anyone know how to fix it?

> Refer the image

[image]

Comment: updating android studio might work

Comment: Well, you have to go with updated [version >3](https://developer.android.com/studio/). Its solved your problem.

Comment: @sourabhkaushik thanks bud! it's currently running on 3.1.4

Comment: Have you solved your problem? if not then just delete this type of settings folder of android studio ".AndroidStudioX.X" where x is your studio version

Answer (score 1):

i guess you have changed the IDE font .
go to setting by control+alt+s ,in the left tab -->(first expandable button , first button) , then in right tab --> Uncheck the second checkbox (Override Default fonts)

Answer (score 0):

there are no options for change language 
so I think you have to uninstall android studio and reinstall it 
or 
download and install alongside a new version

Or check this link:

[How to change android studio Operation language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249177/how-to-change-android-studio-operation-language/29404523#29404523)